Rolling row Subtraction from the previously calculated Value
I have a table of various parameters that are summed up to provide a volume loss per replicate. I would like to create a new column with the Final Volume per Replicate, with the first Replicate being the starting volume minus the volume lost.
Data
replicate=c(1:6)
start=c(2982)
Volume_loss=c(419.29,450.69,409.73,405.67,367.81,448.61)

My attempt, while it gets me the solution, isn't vary elegant and require a lot of repeat code.
mutate(Final_Volume= ifelse(replicate=="1", start-Volume_loss, Volume_loss))
mutate(Final_Volume= if_else(replicate!="1", dplyr::lag(Final_Volume)-Volume_loss,Final_Volume))
mutate(Final_Volume= if_else(replicate!=1:2, dplyr::lag(Final_Volume)-Volume_loss,Final_Volume))
mutate(Final_Volume= if_else(replicate!=1:3, dplyr::lag(Final_Volume)-Volume_loss,Final_Volume))
mutate(Final_Volume= if_else(replicate!=1:4, dplyr::lag(Final_Volume)-Volume_loss,Final_Volume))
mutate(Final_Volume= if_else(replicate!=1:5, dplyr::lag(Final_Volume)-Volume_loss,Final_Volume))

The output would look similar to the Following:


It looks like something is missing from the example data. Did you generate a data frame from those? How does replicate fit into it?

Do you want something like data.frame(start, Volume_loss) |> mutate(Final_Volume = start - cumsum(Volume_loss))?

@JonSpring That seems to be it.
